# ASP.NET header disappearing upon opening view

Tags: asp.net

I have a _layout.cshtml which contains everything but the page-specific body of the website. Within this layout I have a header that looks like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="Content/Images/header.jpg" />
</div>
```

The navigation menu consists of a few ActionLinks that redirect me to the corresponding view.

My problem is that whenever I navigate to a page that is NOT the homepage, the header disappears. I can't see why this would happen, because every _layout is the same, right?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does your other page are in subfolder ? How do you include your layout ?

Comment: Is this the only disappearing element? These other views - do they have Layout property set to `null`?

Comment: My _layout.cshtml is in Views > Shared. The other pages are in other View folders (following the MVC principle).

Comment: And yes, for some reason the header is the only disappearing element. The rest of the page stays intact.
EDIT: It looks like the header source is not found (it displays the generic image icon instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/header.jpg")" />`

Comment: This is even cleaner than my own solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like I used some wrong pathing. The following change in code fixed the problem:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="../Content/Images/header.jpg" />
</div>
```

The child views need an indication that they need to search in the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~ operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based on the current root. In your case use `<img src="~/Content/Images/header.jpg" />`